# ImportError only with sudo when running python app?

Tags: python, docker, anaconda, sudo, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to run some python code with the `sudo` command, but every time I do it, it gives me an Import error. However, if I run, say, `import numpy` in terminal it gives me no errors. Also, if I build a code with several Imports and then run it without the `sudo` command, it gives me no errors and the code runs flawlessly. I already added Defaults `env_keep += "PYTHONPATH"` to the sudoers folder, so that's not the problem. I installed Anaconda3, so maybe that's useful information?

I'm running GNOME Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS. And kernel version 4.4.0-59-generic.

I'm sorry, I'm very new at this, but I'm learning.

I ran `which python` and then I ran `sudo which python` and they gave me different directories.

`sudo which python` gave me `usr/bin/python` `which python` gave me `home/user/anaconda3/bin/python`

I tried running `sudo ./anaconda3/envs/ml/bin/python doc.py` but now it says that it can't find the file.

I'm running it with `sudo` because I need the permission for `docker` to work.

EDIT: trying sudo -E instead of sudo yields the same error.

Comment: Try replacing `sudo` with `sudo -E`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you have is that `sudo` does **not** follow the usual `PATH` order when looking at an executable: it searches the system directories *first*. This is written in the `man sudo`:

> SECURITY NOTES
>    `sudo` tries to be safe when executing external commands.
>
> To prevent command spoofing, **`sudo` checks `"."` and `""` (both denoting current directory) last when searching for a command in the
>   user's `PATH`** (if one or both are in the `PATH`).  Note, however, that the actual `PATH` environment variable is not modified and is passed
>   unchanged to the program that sudo executes.

So, to fix this you have to make sure that the command you give to `sudo` cannot match a system executable, i.e. specify the absolute path:

```
sudo /home/user/anaconda3/bin/python
```

A general command that should work is:

```
sudo "$(which python)"
```

This is because `which python` is executed *before* `sudo`, and its output is passed as an argument to `sudo`. However `sudo` by default does not perform any "shell-like" setup, and may restrict the environment, so you may consider using the `-E` or `-i` flags to make sudo pass the environment untouched and do the proper shell setup.

Comment: I just tried this. I changed the python app to the /home/user/anaconda3/bin/ directory and I ran the
 sudo  /home/user/anaconda3/bin/python mlcode.py 
 code in terminal.
 Now it says that there's no such file or directory there.

Comment: @AaronGonzalez Well, you have to use the correct path. I just copied what you pasted, if it is incorrect I can't do anything about it.

Comment: I figured it out. However, it now says that it can't find the '__main__' module.

Comment: @AaronGonzalez This may be an issue with the environment. Try to add either the `-E` or the `-i` flag to sudo: `sudo -i /home/<user>/.../bin/python`. The `-i` flags tells `sudo` to do the setup as if it was launching a shell, so if you have some environment setup in files like `.bash_profile`/`.bashrc` these are executed.

Comment: I tried these two, but I'm getting the same error. Any more suggestions?

Comment: @AaronGonzalez What error? In any case: I believe you can solve your problem in an other way. You do **not** need `sudo` to use docker. You can simply be in the `docker` group. Do this: `sudo usermod -a -G docker <your-username>` (see `man usermod` to know what this does; don't forget the `-a`!). Then logout and login again (no restart requried, just logout+login or you can use `newgrp docker` to immediately see the change), after this you should be able to execute docker commands without `sudo`.