# Python Permission Problems Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, permissions, anaconda

I am trying to run a simple python script

```
$python Solution.py read_input.txt
```

Only if I use sudo,

```
$sudo python Solution.py read_input.txt
```

I receive the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Solution1.py", line 2, in <module>
   import numpy as np
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

This is due to a permission problem.

```
$which python
/home/andrelandgraf/anaconda3/bin/python

$sudo which python
/usr/bin/python
```

I want to use my anaconda env to run the file but because of permission reasons I am unable to run python without sudo which will lead to running the system version of python that does not have access to numpy.

I tried chmod and chown to give python the required permissions

```
$chmod -R 777 .
```

but whenever I run python without sudo it just prints one empty line and nothing happens.

I also checked my .bashrc file and echoed the $PATH, anaconda3 seems to be installed fine.

```
$PATH: /home/andrelandgraf/anaconda3/bin:/home/andrelandgraf/bin:/home/andrelandgraf/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError only with sudo when running python app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41910567/importerror-only-with-sudo-when-running-python-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sudo` does not use the user `PATH` variable for security reasons. If you want to specify exactly which executable to use you have to use the absolute path:

```
sudo /home/andrelandgraf/anaconda3/bin/python Solution.py read_input.txt
```

I must add: you should run programs as root only if it is *necessary*. In your question you don't say why you need to do this so we cannot help you in fixing the issue with permissions or workarounds.

---

If you want to know why `sudo` does *not* look at what the user has defined as `PATH` that is simple: if a user downloaded a malware that is called, say, `ls` then calling `sudo ls` would run the malware as root which is way worse than running the malware as a anormal user.

so `sudo` only looks at the system defined `PATH` variable, hopefully a normal user cannot put such a malware in a system directory and thus `sudo ls` executes the normal command `ls` as root instead of the malware.